# Retaining employees during a period of high attrition. (Convince senior managers to increase their pay?)

Tags: management

I work in middle management for a 15 member team, 12 of whom are inexperienced and in need of training.

The problem is the 3 experienced members were not happy with their compensation, and have been demanding more for quite some time.

Upper management is silent on this issue. I know that the experienced employees are attending interviews outside the company, although they're unaware I know about their job hunting.

I've approached upper management, asking them to revise the experienced employees' compensation, because they are crucial for the project, but my immediate manager doesn't care.

The 12 new members cannot be easily trained if the experienced staff quit. How can I make my manager understand this?

Comment: Although if you're presenting your arguments in the same sort of language as you're using here ("egotistical", "doesn't care about anything") that's a different problem.

Comment: This really needs editing. It sounds like your company doesn't value the experience of it's staff, it's filled the team with novices and it won't pay it's experienced staff properly. Are you asking what you can do about that?

Comment: @NathanCooper err... yeah. Blatantly not a duplicate of what I flagged it as a duplicate of. Close vote retracted, although I entirely agree it needs editing.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Unless I'm misrepresenting what the OP is asking. I think my comment is a little bit: "hmmm... here's a better question. ask that".

Comment: So your "approaching" didn't work. Management reserves its right and prerogative to be short-sighted. WHY are you continuing to bang your head against the wall -  you can't take "no" or "I don't give a damn" for an answer? Why do you insist on trying to save people from themselves?

Comment: what is your responsibility regarding the hiring of the 12 inexperienced team members? Where are they in their training? If they are not providing value to the team, how many people are needed to perform the functions of the team?

Comment: @Falaki: I've edited your question to seem a bit less subjective and I've made some grammar improvements as well. I hope that it's still ok.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that the 3 senior people won't quit. And the 12 new employees will be trained, and all this without giving the 3 senior people any raises.

Going on a job hunt is not the same thing as quitting. They also have to get offers and then accept them. Once the first senior person quits, your comments may carry some weight, and the senior people may get raises. Until then, management has no reason to worry about attrition.

Keep in mind that until there is real attrition, management would be foolish to pre-emptively give raises. If you want management to be worried about attrition, there has to be some attrition.

Comment: `Until then, management has no reason to worry about attrition.` - I can't help but disagree. Management always needs to worry about attrition in this day and age, especially since their competent staff have been complaining already.

Comment: Loss of productivity is almost the same thing as attrition. If they're actively interviewing, you've lost their hearts, and they're not putting their hearts into their work. That is something quantifiable that management should be worried about. But you're right, _these_ managers are not going worry about people leaving until people actually leave. You can't give everyone who threatens to leave a raise, but this case doesn't look like a bunch of entitled employees trying to manipulate their company.

Comment: I agree that the employees don't seem entitled and manipulative. But management doesn't know that the senior employees are looking around. So it is entirely plausible for them to conclude that everything is fine.

Comment: @JayGodse - If I were an upper-level manager and I'd been told what you've told them, I'd assume that not only where one or more of the seniors job hunting, but that one or more were going to leave.